# Run Docker containers with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, containers

I want to run a Docker container in a Jenkins build and I can´t do that. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins executes jobs which has commands. If you specify some docker commands in the job description, it should get executed.
It might fail if you / the user jenkins is running as, is not permitted to execute those commands.
Check that docker is in your path, check that the jenkins user is in the docker group (at least for debian based distribution).

Comment: Thanks for the response